# Proving predicate logic argument validity?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I spent the past hour pondering on possible solutions for the following task, which is basically to prove the argument validity.

$$\forall x\forall y(P(x, y) \rightarrow Q(x))   \vdash \forall x \exists yP(x, y) \rightarrow \forall xQ(x)$$

Any ideas?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Stick $\neg ((\neg (\forall x\forall y(Pxy \rightarrow Qx)))\to (\forall x \exists yPxy \rightarrow \forall xQx))$ in a tableau; show that it closes.

Comment: [These notes (in pdf form)](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf) explain why the method described in my previous comment works.

Comment: I'm not sure about that actually. I'm sorry - I'm really tired. You can do something similar at any rate. The notes'll clarify things (if you dig deep enough). Perhaps I'll answer in more detail tomorrow.

Comment: @Shaun - using the tableaux method (according to R:Smullyan, *First-Order Logic*, 1968), in order to prove that $\forall x \forall y (P(x,y) \rightarrow Q(x)) \vdash \forall x \exists yP(x,y) \rightarrow \forall xQ(x)$ (call it $A \vdash B$) you must check that $\{ A , \lnot B \}$ is *unsatisfiable*, i.e.that the tableau will close.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: Ah, no wonder I was having doubts; thank you! I had $\neg ((\forall x\forall y(Pxy\rightarrow Qx))\to ( \forall x \exists yPxy \rightarrow \forall xQx))$ in mind then, which is equivalent. Sorry!

Comment: @Shaun - we can mimick P.Smith's proof with tableaux. Call the two formula $A$ and $B$ and start with $\{A, \lnot B \}$. (1) is $A$; (2) is $\lnot B$; (3) $\forall x \exists y P(x,y)$ from (2); (4) $\lnot \forall x Q(x)$ from (2); (5) $\lnot Q(a)$ from (4) with $a$ new; (6-7) $P(a,b)$ from (3) with $b$ new; (8-9) we instantiate (1) with $a$ then $b$, to get : $P(a,b) \rightarrow Q(a)$ ; now we branch it into (10) $\lnot P(a,b)$ and (11) $Q(a)$, and both close matching them respectively with (7) and (5) and we are done !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In natural deduction system, take the premiss and temporarily assume $\forall x\exists yP(x, y)$.

Instantiate the premiss and the temporary assumption with the parameter $a$, to get

> $\forall y(P(a, y) \to Q(a))$
>
> $\exists yP(a, y)$

With a view to using existential elimination, instantiate the existential with a new parameter. WE get

> $\quad|\quad P(a, b)$
>
> $\quad|\quad P(a, b) \to Q(a)$.

modus ponens gives us

> $\quad|\quad Q(a)$.

Since this doesn't involve $b$ we can discharge the assumption at the beginning of the sub proof to get

> $Q(a)$

We can universally quantify as $a$ occurs in no assumption this depends on to get

> $\forall xQ(x)$

Discharge the initial temporary assumption by conditional proof and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, you can prove this by means of the [method of analytic tableaux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux). You assume $$\neg ((\forall x\forall y(Pxy\rightarrow Qx))\to ( \forall x \exists yPxy \rightarrow \forall xQx))$$ then apply a series of contradiction-hunting rules to get

[image],

which is *closed*; that is, each of its paths end in contradictions. Hence $$(\forall x\forall y(Pxy\rightarrow Qx))\to ( \forall x \exists yPxy \rightarrow \forall xQx),$$ which is equivalent to $$\forall x\forall y(Pxy\rightarrow Qx)\vdash  \forall x \exists yPxy \rightarrow \forall xQx.$$ The explanation for this last step is beyond my ability just yet.

This can then be used to construct a proof like Peter's as Mauro describes in the comments.

Comment: the last sept is simply this; from : $A \rightarrow B$, assume $A$ and apply *modus ponens* to get : $A \vdash B$. With tableaux method, instead of starting with the single formula $\lnot (A \rightarrow B)$, you will apply it to the two-elements set $\{A, \lnot B \}$.

Comment: Thank you. But applying it to $\neg (A\to B)$ is equivalent to applying it to $\{ A, \neg B\}$: it's a preference of mine (when $\neg (A\to B)$ is not too long).